# What is the meaning of "La niaise! En botte!"?

Tags: sens, traduction, expressions, choix-de-mot, littérature

I'm reading *Guignol's Band* by Louis-Ferdinand Céline, and in the prologue there's this passage:

"Quelle objection! Quelle tourterie! Ah! attention! La niaise! En botte! Volent habillons! Émouvez bon Dieu!"

Does anyone know what "*La niaise! En botte!*" mean?

Does "*La niaise*" refer to "*Quelle objection*"?

Is "*En botte*" an expression?

I find this passage very difficult to understand, would certainly appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

*Le marchand de sottises.* Spontanément ça m'a donné l'impression qu'il s'agissait d'une réduction de la *niaise(rie)* et de l'idée de quantité. Le mot [*botte*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/botte/0) a plusieurs sens, mais au singulier avec la préposition *en*, le sens de produits de même nature réunis ensemble en une unité destinée à la vente etc., précise l'idée de quantité (celle dont dispose le marchand par exemple, possiblement *beaucoup*). Et le foin que l'ont met *en botte* devient une *botte de foin*. Ce qu'on mettrait *en botte* ici serait la *niaise*, un adjectif substantivé que j'assimile à la [niaiserie](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/niaiserie). Je ne sais pas si quelqu'un de plus familier que moi avec l'argot y entendrait autre chose...

> Céline reprend en 1944 dans la préface de *Guignol's Band I* cette idée
> selon laquelle le sujet apparent d'une œuvre d'art n'a de valeur
> qu'autant qu'il permet de susciter cette émotion qu'il revient à
> l'artiste de transposer par les moyens du rythme et de l'harmonie. Les
> bagarres qui se multiplient autour de Ferdinand dans la première
> partie du roman sont en effet présentées par l'auteur comme de simples
> prétextes à un travail d'écriture révolutionnaire, qui doit permettre
> à l'émotion de donner sa pleine mesure, et avoir pour effet de rendre
> immédiatement obsolète toute littérature qui renoncerait à en faire
> autant :
>
> [on cite un extrait contenant l'extrait en question]
>
> C'est dans cette écriture expressive et décousue dont ce passage tout
> en interjections et en juxtapositions donne un exemple que le sujet
> apparemment futile du roman trouve sa justification : les
> échauffourées grotesques qui se multiplient dans *Guignol's Band*
> constituent le meilleur point de départ pour la transposition de cette
> émotion que l'écrivain a la charge d'exprimer. Cette dévaluation du
> sujet qu'il présente comme une révolution permet ainsi à Céline de
> prétendre au titre de successeur littéraire des peintres
> impressionnistes [...]
>
> Rémi Wallon. [*La musique du fond des choses : destruction, savoir et
> création dans les écrits de Louis-Ferdinand Céline.*](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-02306487v2/document)  Littératures.
> Université Sorbonne Paris Cité, 2017.  Français.  NNT : 2017US-PCC250.
> tel-02306487v2, à la page 143.

C'est dans ce contexte que s'inscrit la préface, et cette série d'interjections ressemblent un peu à des feux d'artifice et je ne sais pas si l'analyse des pièces pyrotechniques individuelles mène à une quelconque révélation de la pensée de l'auteur, au-delà du [style](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Ferdinand_C%C3%A9line#Le_style_de_C%C3%A9line).

J'ai aussi jeté un coup d’œil à [une traduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=qD2B3hUXeZsC&lpg=PP1&dq=Guignol%27s%20Band%20I&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q=Guignol%27s%20Band%20I&f=false) en langue anglaise pour y constater le choix des mots « [dopi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dopey)ness » et « [by the](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+yard) [yard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yard%20goods) » pour rendre ces deux éléments en interjection. Il y a concordance entre ce choix et mon impression de *niaiserie/en quantité*, et je trouve cette interprétation plausible en contexte mais on est loin d'une démonstration...

---

- That could be *silliness*/*loads of it*.
- I don't think there's a connection with *objection*.
- *(Mettre) en botte* is to bunch/bundle together ; something *en botte* is so bunched/bundled together, like flowers/hay etc.

Comment: *Objection* peut être synonyme de *critique/réfutation/réplique* ; *tourterie* a pour définition *bêtise/ânerie* (https://www.languefrancaise.net/Bob/23669) ; Habit  comme racine de *habillons* donne : petits habits (linge de corps) ; le tout, "Volent habillons!", serait de nos jours : "À poils!"

Comment: Bien vu pour le sens possible de *volent habillons !*. J'avais interprété *babilllons* comme "personnages qui babillent* ou *babillages*. De toute façon, comme tu l'écris,  le sens précis de chaque interjection n'est probablement pas si important que ça. Je sens plus un jeu de mot sur *Volent papillons !*

Answer (score 1):

There are two possibilities

**A** en botte
— wrapped in a bundle, into a bundle

**B** en bottes
— wrapped in  bundles
— wearing boots

You find  23 occurrences of the word "botte" in the book, out of which 5 are preceded by "en". The first and the last only of the occurrences preceded by "en" are in the singular, which means that, if there is no error or case for poetic license, in these two occurrences the author is talking about a bundle.

All occurrences have been collected below, each with the text that contains them, so as to situate them better and so as to facilitate further research if a new idea arises.

***en botte(s)***

1. (p. 8)  À vous de comprendre ! Émouvez-vous ! « C'est que des bagarres tous vos
   chapitres ! » Quelle objection ! Quelle tourterie ! Ah ! attention ! La niaise !
   En botte ! Volent habillons ! Émouvez bon Dieu !
2. (p. 52) qu'après ça... à lui les mignonnes !... Caïd et tout et revendeur ! La Police ça les
   gêne pas !... des hypocrites !... Toutes les mômes en bottes pour les
   Corses !... pour les Belges !... pour n'importe qui !... Ah ! cette affaire !
   Business fameux !... Moi je sais ce qu'il gamberge le futé !
3. (p. 107) Ceux qui peuvent rester ils
   restent pas ! On les bute ? ils sont pas contents ! Ils savent pas ce qu'ils
   veulent !... Merde !... C'est la fin des bonnes manières ! La vacherie en
   bottes ! »
   Ah ! Il se marrait tout de même au fond !... On voyait bien qu'il
   taquinait... qu'il nous faisait marcher... Croquemitaine !
4. (p. 624)  C'est pas drôle le petit matin... La
   sueur du tramway à Londres ça sent les soutes des bateaux... les voyages
   aux antipodes ! dans les Orients, les passes malaises, à cause des pipes, des
   tabacs au miel... au santal un peu.
   Ils y pensent peut-être aussi les employés du tramway, en boîte, en
   bottes, cahotant dur, ramponnant les uns dans les autres, aux aiguillages,
   aux coins des rues, déballant sec, cahin-caha, de High Point à Shepperd,
5. (p. 680) Sosthène lui il était fixé. Il se caillait plus le mou. Il voulait
   plus se remuer pour rien. Il attendait l'accomplissement de la prophétie,
   que les bourriques viennent nous cueillir. Là tous là en botte. Il le
   pariait devant les domestiques. C'était entendu.

For cases 2 and 3 there is no way to tell which is which; case 4, for instance, in which "en bottes" is preceded by "en boîte" shows that there is a case of "bundle in the plural": "en boite" means "tinned" (French: sardines en boite, English: tinned sardines), and this reminds one of bundles, bunches (bunch of radishes); this analogy tends to confirm very much the idea of bundle in this occurrence.

There is possibly a connection between "1" and "2"; "La niaise" can only be a person of the feminine sex; in "2" we find "les mômes en bottes"; "les mômes" is a pejorative term used for rather young women, and here, apparently, from the context, for young prostitutes; however, it is difficult to conclude anything and speculation is the reader's only resource, in other words incomprehension (this is likely so because of design : "À vous de comprendre !"). Are we to understand "batches" of young prostitutes assigned to certain clients in groups (Corsicans, Belgians, …)? There is little doubt from the word "pour" that whether "en bottes" means "booted" or "bundled" the purpose of either is to serve, in some way, the Corsicans, the Belgians, and others.

***botte(s)***

1. (p. 33) Ship Chandlers qu'était son blot, tout le
   matériel du marin, tout ce qu'il faut pour l'équipage, pour le capitaine.
   Des couteaux, des bottes comme ça, et des lanternes, des falots de toutes
   les couleurs et puis du dé un peu faisan et de la saumure
2. (p. 124) elle bêle d'horreur... Elle veut se
   sauver... elle peut pas !... Tout retombe sur elle !... Le vieux veut l'aider,
   l'extirper ! il tire dessus, là par les bottes... il s'arc-boute... ho ! hisse ! et
   hop !... toute la camelote redégringole !...
3. (p.132) Boro pour se faire de la place, il repoussait tout, à droite, à gauche... à
   grands coups de bottes... Il piquait un crincrin dans le tas, un saxo, un
   piccolo, mandoline... il taquinait le truc un petit peu... comme çi,
   comme ça... un air prélude..

[*next occurrence - "botte" means "to kick".*]

4. (p. 162) Il va défoncer le
   grand sofa ! Il reste là croulé ! moi alors j'y vas ! je monte dessus ! là sur
   son gros corps ! je le piétine ! je le botte ! je lui fous une grande
   claque !... je vais là-bas exprès !
5. (p. 172) « Et la poupée ?... Elle bouge pas ?... »
   Elle est affalée... elle repleure !... Je lui file un coup de botte dans les
   côtes... histoire qu'elle se redresse !... Elle pousse un grand hurlement...
   Elle réagit et furax !...
6. (p. 214) Je suis prêt à tout défoncer !... je ramponne
   terrible !... à coups de bottes !... On m'entrouvre à la fin tout de
   même !... une fissure... je bouscule tout ! j'emboutis... l'huissier !.

[*next occurrence - figurative use of "botte", servility*]

7. (p. 282) « Drinks ! » commande le colonel.
   Un larbin s'empresse, arrive à la botte... toute une cave de bouteilles,
   flacons, whisky, cognac, champagne, cherry...
8. (p. 289) Il veut nous épater de son luxe... Il fait le grand seigneur
   à présent... Un colonel ! shako ! grand sabre ! magnifique alors !... du
   gala !... brandebourgs ! bottes ! éperons !... moulé kaki et rouge revers !...
   Ah ! il est incroyable sa bouille !
9. (p. 317) La table est servie ! Voilà le colonel ! et la croûte ! Ils se sont changés
   tous les deux... en bleu de chauffe, hautes bottes caoutchouc... fini le
   chinois et l'opérette... sérieux tous les deux... absolument experiments !

[next occurrence - possible use of "botte" as "bundle"*]

10. (p. 423) Mireille la femme à Gendremer avec sa robe prune... tout ça en plein
    boum !... je les reconnaissais toutes... Si elles se défendaient,
    virevolaient, te piquaient du kaki à la botte, à l'arraché... c'était par
    armées que ça godait ! que ça venait ! c'était l'heure !

[*next occurrence - surreal figure of speech in which spurred boots become "iron boots"*]

11. (p. 616) je vais le vider le sale outil ! C'est plus supportable ! Il m'étreigne le
    féroce... il se doute ! ses deux bottes de fer ! un coup de ma terrible
    croupe, je pars, envole, prodige dans l'essor !
12. (p. 616) Heureux bon Dieu j'ai plus de
    culotte !... Je suis cheval de bataille pas pour rire... la croupe à poil... à
    poil et nerfs !... et fort monté ! Voilà comme je charge ! au 17e lourd
    botte à botte... trois mille cinq cents cavaliers !... et des masses en plus !
    écumes cœur au vent la bourrasque !...

[*next occurrence - symbolism: "boot" as symbol of domination*]

13. (p. 619) Quand j'aurai
    repris toute ma vigueur je vous ferai faire les douze escaliers !... chacals à
    ma botte ! monstres ! cochons !... » Ils en rotent... je les domine je les
    traite caca... Ils ont pas fini !... Je veux qu'ils me massent la région du
    cœur
14. (p. 634) Je le repère par terre, au
    trottoir, ils sont deux colosses qui le sonnent, en train de le finir, l'un au
    bâton l'autre à coups de botte...
15. (p. 673) C'est tout du vampire et perfide ! tu sautes gentleman ! ils t'enlèvent la
    peau ! C'est ça l'étranger pour eux, une peau pour leurs bottes ! J'ai la
    pratique ! j'ai payé ! Je vois tout ça venir !

[*next occurrence - symbolism: "boot" as symbol of domination*]

16. (p. 714) Il peut plus tout
    seul ! Il hurle partout, des hauts, des fonds, que ça rallège ! qu'on se
    magne à sa botte ! Ça charrie, ça traîne, ça grognasse et puis ça
    déboule...

[*next occurrence - apparently, the idea of "bundle"*]

17. (p. 720) J'irais parfaitement ! À moi
    l'Amérique ! La Plata zaussi ! Oui ! La poisse resterait par ici ! C'est pas
    une botte de petits taquins !...
    « Je vous dresserai ! que je leur crie !
18. (p. 778) elle veut ramener
    le monde... elle veut son effet... Cascade arrive par derrière, lui file un
    coup de botte au cul qu'elle est enlevée à trois mètres. Elle rebondit, elle
    te pousse un cri que ça couvre tout, le bruit du canon !

There is no doubt that some of the symbolism associated with boots (found as "botte" or "bottes" in the text) is one of the author's devices to express various notions more or less vividly, essentially servility and domination. In the 18 occurrences that precede, the word is almost in all cases used with the meaning of "boot" or a related one. There is no evident indication from the extract containing "botte"  that a special meaning is attached to this word in connection with the sense "bundle".